# Inserting select box in the CKEditor Text Area

Tags: html, ckeditor

Is it possible to insert HTML select box in the text area of CKEditor ?
I have been able to find and execute samples, where select boxes can be developed as a plugin and added as toolbar option.

Since, the text behind CKEditor text area is basically HTML, how can I develop a toolbar plugin which allows me to add select box and the values as well in the CKEditor text area.

Thanks

Comment: I believe the question needed clarification. It looks better now and hence downvotes are not needed anymore

Answer (score 0):

There is an official [Form Elements](http://ckeditor.com/addon/forms) plugin available that you can [add to your build](http://ckeditor.com/builder). It is a part of the Full preset and you can test it on the [demo here](http://ckeditor.com/demo#full).